# Java Queues and Stacks

Tags: java, stack, queue

I have a small problem that I'm hoping someone could help me with.
This is an assignment, so I am not supposed to use classes imported from the java API nor am I supposed to do this in any other way (arraylist would have made this much easier.)
I created a Queue class and a Stack class. 
I am trying to retrieve the head of the Queue, and add it to the Stack. 
I am guessing I will need to create a method that somehow gets the value of the head of the list and stores it so I can use it. 
For example, if I enqueued " bob", "jack", and "jill" to the Queue in that order, it will look like:

bob

jack

jill

I want to dequeue bob from the queue list, but add him to the head of the Stack list, but I can't figure out how. I'm sorry if my question is not very precise, I'm having problems wording what I really need. If any other information is needed I will update my post. Thanks for any help.

Here is my Queueclass:
(LL is my Link List class)

```
public class Queue<T extends Comparable<T>> {

LL<T> theQueue;

public Queue() {
    theQueue = new LL<T>();
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return theQueue.isEmpty();
}

public void enqueue(T value) {
    theQueue.insertTail(value);
}

public T dequeue() throws QueueException {
T retval = null;
try {
retval=theQueue.deleteHead();

}catch (LLException e) {
throw new QueueException ("Queue is empty");
}
return retval;}

public String toString() {
    return theQueue.toString();

   }}
```

And my Stack Class:

```
public class Stack<T extends Comparable<T>>{
LL<T> theStack;

 public Stack()
 {
   theStack = new LL<T>();
}

 public boolean isEmpty()
  {
    return theStack.isEmpty();
   }

     public void push(T value)
  {
    theStack.insertHead(value);
  }

   public T pop() throws StackException
   {
     T retval = null;
     try
    {
      retval = theStack.deleteHead();
     }
     catch (LLException e)
    {
       throw new StackException("Stack Underflow");
     }
    return retval;
   }

   public boolean isFull()
   {
     return false;
   }

   public String toStrin()
  {
    return theStack.toString();
  }
```

Main Class:

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack <String> hired = new Stack<String>();
    Stack <String> fired = new Stack<String>();
    Queue <String> apps = new Queue<String>();
    String temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of the action to perform:");
        System.out.println("1. Accept Application");
        System.out.println("2. Hire");
        System.out.println("3. Fire");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int key = kb.nextInt();

        switch (key) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter applicant's name and ID separated by semi-colon:");
                String applicant = kb.next() + "\n";
                System.out.println("You entered " + applicant);

                apps.enqueue(applicant);
                break;

            case 2: 
                try{
                 temp = apps.dequeue();
                } catch (QueueException s) {
                } 

                try{ apps.dequeue(); }
                catch (QueueException s){ 
                    System.out.println("Queue is empty");} 
                hired.push(temp);

            case 3:
                System.out.println();


            case 4: System.out.println("Bye");
        System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

So it won't let me assign `apps.dequeue()` to `temp` without the try and catch. but then when I do `hired.push(temp);` I get an error saying temp may have not been initialized.

Comment: You should show what you've done so far.

Comment: I have too many classes I thought that would be a lot of code to post. But I'll show something.

Comment: You should take a `Stack` as a parameter in your queue. Don't you think? :)

Comment: @hugoSousa What do you mean by that?

Comment: It should be something like `public T dequee(Stack s)`, so you know which `Stack` you should add the element.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't see how this could solve my issue. The actual assignment is to allow the user to input names used as applications for hiring them. The applications must be stored in a queue, because its first applied first hired. Once someone is hired, there application is removed from the queue list, and added to the "hired" stack. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's not the solution, just a step for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is "To dequeue "bob" from the Queue and add it to the Stack", isn't it?
So I think you have already tell what to do:

```
Queue<String> q = new Queue<String>(); 
Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
// ... enqueue three strings
String temp = q.dequeue();
s.push(temp);
```

Yes - this task has nothing to do with the implementation of your Queue and Stack class. It's only about using the interface. As long as you have implemented them correctly, these code work.

**EDIT**
So maybe this is what you want:

```
String temp = ""; // explicitly initialize
try {
    temp = q.dequeue();
    s.push(temp);
} catch {
}
```

I put both dequeue and push in try block: if dequeue fails, nothing is to be pushed. Is this right for you ?

Comment: I get an incompatible type message when I try this because of the templates. If I could find a way to fix that without error without removing my templates then this would be the ideal solution.

Comment: @Mjalil93 What error do you get? They both use the same `T`, which is `String` in the example.

Comment: It says "comparable cannot be converted to string". I even tried using `T` instead of `String` but it didn't help.

Comment: @Mjalil93 `q` is a `Queue<String>`, not just a plain `Queue`, right?

Comment: @immibis What do you mean? Yes, my inputs are Strings, but the original queue was created as a generic template one.

Comment: @Mjalil93 I think you may have to explicit declare the type, like `Queue <String> q = new Queue <String> ();`

Comment: @Mjalil93 If your actual queue (the instance, and the reference to it, not the `Queue` class) isn't a `Queue<String>`, then how can the compiler know it's a queue of strings?

Comment: @hugoSousa Okay, Thanks. So that fixed the incompatible type error. Now i just have to add a try and catch to it and I'll let you guys know if it works. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Alright so I added the missing `<String>` to the declarations and that fixed most issues. Now I am running into a different problem because `temp` is assigned a value within a try and catch so when I try to use that value outside the try and catch it says the variable may not have been given a value. I'm going to update the main class in the original post to show you what I mean.

Comment: @mengWang Thank you very much!! Worked perfectly. Now I can continue with the rest of the program. Thanks a lot to everyone. The people on this site are 100x better that the assistant teacher who's job is to help us with our labs lol. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use iterator (if you need to push value from a random position of queue into stack). For your assignment, simply dequeue method should work fine as pointed in another answer.
Before calling the dequeue method, call this iterator and check if hasNext(). if true, get the value using iterator.next() and store it.
Now you have the value in 'head' position. Now call dequeue method and delete the head value. Now simply push your stored value into stack

Comment: I am not familiar with iterator. I feel like this is the solution, but can you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: iterator actually is used to iterator  through the elements. Iterator is like (read as NOT SAME), like you use for-each loop. It is used for iterating (walking) through a list, especially when the next element is attached with earlier one through a 'link'. Unlike array where you know the index of elements, in a list you just have a link to next element, you do not know the last elements and so on. So all you can do is traverse through it.....one element at a time.... using an iterator.

Comment: General format for using iterator is(u can also add generics to it):


Iterator it = nameOfTheList.iterator(); 
while(it.hasNext()){
value = it.next();
}

first line is used for declaring the iterator over the 'list' that you want to traverse on. Second is to check if there is any 'next element'. Third line: if there is a link to next element, get its value

Comment: PS: i read your question again, actually you do not need all this iterator stuff for your assignment. All you need is to use dequeue. When you dequeue , element from Head position of your queue is removed. Now since you have the value that was present in HEAD, simply take that value and push it into the stack and you are done.

Use this iterator stuff if you want to push some random position value into the stack.